# How can I switch between Nouveau and INTEL video driver?

Tags: nvidia, intel, nouveau

On laptops with NVIDIA Optimus, Nouveau is installed by default. 
When you try to install closed-source driver of NVIDIA, it's possible to switch between NVIDIA and INTEL video driver via NVIDIA's control center.

But what if I don't want to install the closed-source driver, will I be able to switch to INTEL driver from Nouveau? How?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. By default, the system will be use Intel as primary gfx of your system if you use Nouveau driver. If you want to use your Nvidia gfx you need to add `DRI_PRIME=1` in front of your application launcher or executable like this one `DRI_PRIME=1 yourApps`. 
You can try doing test in your terminal using command bellow

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"
```

This would give you output like this

```
OpenGL vendor string: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on NV108
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.0.7
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 17.0.7
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

This mean that you run glxinfo using Nouveau driver